# Spring MVC full code request mapping not found

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, jboss

I am trying to implement a Spring mvc application, deploy it on JBoss and be able to call it through my browser.

My WebConfig:

```
package com.heatmanofurioso.concertlivecheck.webapp;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

public class WebConfig implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    //Defining web xml
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.register(SpringApplicationConfig.class);
    rootContext.setServletContext(servletContext);

    //Registering servlet
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");

    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
}
}
```

jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>CLC</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Login Controller

```
package com.heatmanofurioso.concertlivecheck.plugin.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class LoginController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String greeting5(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World1") String name) {
    return "Test" + name;
}
}
```

SpringApplicationConfig

```
package com.heatmanofurioso.concertlivecheck.webapp;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
"com.heatmanofurioso.concertlivecheck",
"com.heatmanofurioso.concertlivecheck.plugin"})
public class SpringApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
}
```

My spring versions are all the latest 4.x release, and all declared on my main pom
My webapp pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<artifactId>webapp</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.heatmanofurioso.concertlivecheck</groupId>
    <artifactId>ConcertLiveCheck</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--Project modules-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.heatmanofurioso.concertlivecheck</groupId>
        <artifactId>utils</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.heatmanofurioso.concertlivecheck</groupId>
        <artifactId>database</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.heatmanofurioso.concertlivecheck</groupId>
        <artifactId>service</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.heatmanofurioso.concertlivecheck</groupId>
        <artifactId>plugin</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>${parent.artifactId}</warName>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/../../../../../deployments/</outputDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
</project>
```

My project structure:
[image]

I have an example jsp file, which my browser can find and read at localhost:8080/CLC
But, when i attempt to enter a mapped route, like localhost:8080/CLC/test
I get a 404

Any tips on what might be the root to my problem?

P.S. JBoss output: [image]

Also, not sure if it's relevant, but Spring version is 4.3.10-release, and JBoss is Wildly

Update:
So, i downgraded spring version to 4.3.7-release and everything is working now, any idea on the why? I also certified that before downgrading maven was bundling every single component with the same spring version

Comment: Could you please try this: dispatcher.addMapping("/*");  just to make sure that Dispatcher Servlet will handle all your request.

Comment: What about `localhost:8080/CLC/test?name=test` ?

Comment: @StanislavL Supposedly the parameter would have nothing to do with the request itself being sent, the variable would go null. Or am i wrong? Anyways, thank you and i tried it. But no good :(

Comment: @DanielC. If i do that, i can't even access my index.jsp, i get a forbidden when doing so

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to expose the application name, try to just make a GET request for:

```
http://localhost:8080/test
```

---

If you want to add one more level to your URL, you can do this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "CLC/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String greeting5(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World1") String name) {
    return "Test" + name;
}
```

Comment: Still getting not found.
Also, shouldn't JBoss map my context to the first element on my ip, and then the mapping go next to it? So, context = "CLC", mapping = "test", path "localhost:8080/CLC/test"?

Comment: Can you be sure about the running status of you application?

Comment: Yes, since my index.jsp can be found with "localhost:8080/CLC", with the text i inserted on it "Hello World". Also added a print of JBoss ouput

Answer (score 0):

The latest spring security uses spring core 4.3.7, and i was using spring core 4.3.10.

These libraries were having conflict in my jars.

I downgraded my spring core to 4.3.7 and everything worked fine

Comment: I had same problem, downgrade to 4.3.9 resolved my problem, but what is the problem?